# Which differents containers can I use to run my GWT project in production mode?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, containers

I am using Glassfish at the moment, but I want to know several alternatives; mostly because potential hosting limitations.
I have read that Tomcat is another option too, but it would be nice to know as many alternatives as posible.

Comment: How about JBoss ?? Still many possibilities ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RequestFactoryServlet` and GWT-RPC `RemoteServiceServlet`s can be deployed in **any** servlet container: Tomcat, Jetty, JBoss AS/Wildfly, TJWS, Undertow, Winstone, etc.

If you use neither RequestFactory nor GWT-RPC, then GWT is **only** a client-side solution, and you can use it with any server-side technology (or even no server side at all): PHP, Rails, etc.

With a little bit of work, you can also make RequestFactory work in any Java HTTP server (Sun HTTP Server, Netty, Grizzly, etc.)

What will really limit you in portability are the other features from your container that you may use (EJB, CDI, etc.)

Comment: I'm using GWT-RPC to communicate with server side. I can see that there are many posibilities and the key words to keep looking are _servlet container_. Thanks.

Comment: As an aditional information: When looking for a container in a GWT project, the only thing that I need to know is which container can "contain" my server side and the features I am using on it?